# Quadratic Residues Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

This is a problem that came up on my recent exam and have not been able to solve:

> Let $p$ be an odd prime and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $p \nmid a$. Show that if $x^2 \equiv a$ (mod $p$) has a solution, then it has **exactly** two solutions.

After doing some independent research of my own, I found out that this question is related to the topic of [quadratic residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) and this topic was not covered during lecture prior to being tested. In any case, to approach this question, I would begin by letting $s$ be a solution and then show from there that there exists **exactly** two. Thus, we have

> $s^2 \equiv a$ (mod $p$)

Additionally, we can say that $-s$ is also another solution since when we square this term, we get $s^2$ on the LHS of the congruence. So, if this is the case, then

> If $s \equiv -s$ (mod $p$) $\implies$ $2s \equiv 0$ (mod $p$). Then, $p | s$ since $p$ is an odd prime...

Where do I go from here? Im assuming we would get a contradiction of some sort, but don't know how to proceed any further.

Comment: This is just a standard field theoretic result, no need to invoke the theory of quadratic residues. A polynomial of degree $n$ can not have more than $n$ roots in a field.

Comment: Why do you think $-s \equiv s \pmod p?$ You have $-s \equiv p-s \pmod p.$

Comment: @gammatester I have edited the question. I meant to say "if".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you said, if $s$ is a solution, then so is $-s$. We also know that since $p \nmid a$, that $s \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$, and so $s$ and $-s$ are distinct solutions, and so there are at least two solutions.

Now note that if $x$ is a solution, then we have that $$ x^2 \equiv a \equiv s^2 \pmod p, $$ and so $p \mid (x - s)(x + s)$. Since $p$ is prime, this implies that either $p \mid x - s$, or $p \mid x + s$, and so we see that any solution $x$ must be congruent to either $s$ or $-s$ modulo $p$, showing that $s$ and $-s$ are in fact the only solutions.

Answer (score 2):

> Let $p$ be an odd prime and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $p \nmid a$. Show that if $x^2 \equiv a$ (mod $p$) has a solution, then it has **exactly** two solutions [in the least residue system modulo $p$].

If think that's necessary because without those bracketed words, there are infinitely many solutions.

Take for example $p = 7$ and $a = 2$. This should immediately suggest the solution $x = 3$. But then $3, 10, 17, 24, 31, \ldots$ are also solutions, but of these only $x = 3$ satisfies $0 < x < p$.

As you've already realized, $x$ can be negative. So $x = -3$ is also a solution. Obviously $x - (-x) = 2x$, and therefore even, but $p$ is odd. So $-3 + 7 = 4$, and it just so happens that $x = 4$ is also a solution satisfying $0 < x < p$.

So if $x$ is a solution in the residue system, then $p - x$ is also a solution. But you have to show these are the only ones in the residue system. Well, I see Dylan already covered that, so I'll end on that note.